# Can't fix mongoose overwrite model error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I am using angular-fullstack generator and I have added a Model person. When I try to require the person model in the seed.js file I get this error.

```
    /Users/dev/wishlist/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:334
      throw new mongoose.Error.OverwriteModelError(name);
            ^
OverwriteModelError: Cannot overwrite `Person` model once compiled.
    at Mongoose.model (/Users/dev/wishlist/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:334:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/dev/wishlist/server/api/wishList/person.model.js:11:27)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/dev/wishlist/server/api/wishList/wishList.controller.js:4:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
```

I followed the same structure used for the "Thing" model that comes with the generator. Also did a search and where Person is in the code base and its only in the person.model.js and in the controller.

person.model.js:

```
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var PersonSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  quote: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Person', PersonSchema);
```

wishlist.controller.js:

```
'use strict';

var _ = require('lodash');
var Person = require('./person.model');

// Get all the People that have wish lists
exports.getPeople = function(req, res) {
  Person.find(function (err, people) {
    if(err) { return handleError(res, err); }
    return res.json(200, people);
  });
};

function handleError(res, err) {
  return res.send(500, err);
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: i'm running into the same problem, and though the suggestion below seems to "fix" my problem it's hard to believe that would be the right way to fix it.

Answer (score 4):

As I understand from the information that you posted, the issue appears to be caused by the following lines:

**at Object. (/Users/dev/wishlist/server/api/wishList/person.model.js:11:27)**

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('Person', PersonSchema);
```

**at Object. (/Users/dev/wishlist/server/api/wishList/wishList.controller.js:4:14)**

```
var Person = require('./person.model');
```

This error most commonly comes from a mismatching between Mongoose models.

Somewhere along the road, you have defined this model under a different name, but the same Schema.

In order to see if this is the thing that causes your error, add this code in `person.model.js` right after you require `mongoose`:

```
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.models = {};
mongoose.modelSchemas = {};
```

This will clear out your mongoose data and empty out all existing models and schemas.

I found the aforementioned information at the following [LINK](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/1251).

I have also found some additional discussions that address this issue [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19051041/cannot-overwrite-model-once-compiled-mongoose) and [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14641834/how-to-get-rid-of-error-overwritemodelerror-cannot-overwrite-undefined-mode).

Comment: Thanks Vlad that fixed it. I am concerned with this solution though as this could empty out the other schemas I create. I read the articles you linked and none of them really fix my problem. I understand what is going wrong I just cant figure out where it is going wrong. As far as I can tell I am only defining the schema once.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran in to same error few weeks ago. After trying out few things I came out with a simple fix:

just try to export person model this way -

module.exports.PersonModel = mongoose.model('Person', PersonSchema);

instead of - module.exports = mongoose.model('Person', PersonSchema);

Hope this helps !

if you still get the error just the paths in the modules you were exporting this model.