# NodeJS and mongoDB - mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying manipulate a JSON that wasn't created by me, only uploaded to mongo. In NodeJs I'm trying:

```
app.get('/municipios', async (req, res) => {
  let cidadeSchema = new Schema({}, { strict: false })
  let cidades = mongoose.model('municipios', cidadeSchema)
  let cidade = cidades.findOne({name: 'Rio Grande'})
  // console.log(cidade)
  res.send(CircularJSON.stringify(cidade))
})
```

but when the JSON is sent, it send only the structure of request to mongo, and if I try once, I receive a message: (node:24536) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: OverwriteModelError: Cannot overwrite `municipios` model once compiled.

Answer (score 0):

As you are writing the query inside an async method, so you need to await the result of the findOne Query.
Below is the snippet of the answer

```
app.get('/municipios', async (req, res) => {
  let cidadeSchema = new Schema({}, { strict: false })
  let cidades = mongoose.model('municipios', cidadeSchema)
  let cidade = await cidades.findOne({name: 'Rio Grande'})
  // convert the dataset into object
  cidade = cidade.toObject();
  res.send(cidade)
})
```

After the await, you will get the model data, which you can convert into an object.

Comment: Now I'm receiving this error: OverwriteModelError: Cannot overwrite `municipios` model once compiled.

Comment: At which line you are getting the error, as `municipios` model is just used once

Answer (score 0):

The submitted await answer notices one issue, and you need to fix that also, but it doesn't answer your original issue of OverwriteModelError.

I think you are defining your model schema twice.

The accepted answer in [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14641834/how-to-get-rid-of-error-overwritemodelerror-cannot-overwrite-undefined-mode) has a decent explanation of defining your models separately from your other code and it should help you in your issue